# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. in build.gradle for flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, build.gradle

I am trying to add Firebase to my flutter project, but when I run it in debug mode I am getting an error.

The instructions of how to add the Firebase SDK to my project shows that my `build.gradle` file is different from what Google says it should be. I have looked things up and I thought I had added the correct lines to the file.

Here are the instruction for adding the Firebase SDK to my flutter project:

[image]

This is my project>android>app>build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-servides"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.deal_diligence"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
}
```

Here is the `build.gradle` file from project>android>build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }

    plugins {
        id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false <<< ERROR HERE
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the error I am getting:
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\build.gradle' line: 14
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_c3pybmo0bbk86suaedh5ircie$_run_closure1$_closure4@7f9d876a] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

I should have all the latest and greatest since I created this project yesterday. How do I fix this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you say this is a Flutter app, I recommend following the documented steps to [setting up Firebase in a Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android). There's no need to modify any Gradle files for this.